# Why does ReplaceAll match pattern while MatchQ fails

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

Why does the following pattern with `MatchQ` fail

```
MatchQ[1+Sin[1] I, a_Complex /; Im[a] > 0]
(* False *)
```

Whereas, the same pattern with `ReplaceAll` works?

```
1 + Sin[1] I /. {a_Complex /; Im[a] > 0 -> 3}
(* 1+3Sin[1] *)
1 - Sin[1] I /. {a_Complex /; Im[a] > 0 -> 3}
(* 1-iSin[1] *)
```

If I look at the `FullForm` of my expression it is 
`Plus[1,Times[Complex[0,1],Sin[1]]]`. Shouldn't `a_Complex` match `Complex[0,1]` and `Im[a] == 1 > 0` evaluate to `True`? At least that's what seems to be happening with `ReplaceAll` but I can't quite figure out why `MatchQ` fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MatchQ` matches the whole expression. It doesn't match inner rules.

```
In[1]:= MatchQ[12345, _Integer]
Out[1]= True

In[2]:= MatchQ[{12345}, _Integer]
Out[2]= False
```

`ReplaceAll` works recursively over a whole function, replacing all instances of that pattern it finds. That's the meaning of `All` in the function name.

A careful reading of the usage messages for `MatchQ` and `ReplaceAll` would have explained this.

Comment: +1 We can detect whether any subexpression matches the pattern by using `!FreeQ[...]`, for example...   `! FreeQ[1 + Sin[1] I, a_Complex /; Im[a] > 0]`.

Comment: I did read the documentation before asking. It wasn't really specified that MatchQ only looks to match the outer expression. Although ReplaceAll did note that it attempts to 'transform each subpart of an expression'.

Comment: @void, instead of "outer expression", it's "entire expression"; the intent of `MatchQ[expr, patt]` is to check if `expr` *itself* matches the pattern `patt`, not any sub-expressions `expr` might have.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. Ah ok. Thank you for the clarification, that makes more sense. So essentially `Im[a] > 0` would evaluate to be true, but `a_Complex` wouldn't match as the head of the entire expression is `Plus` not `Complex`. If I wanted to match the `Complex` I'd have to have a pattern that matches nested Heads right?

Comment: @void, something like that, yes; however, `a_ /; Im[a] > 0` is already fine, or you can do `a_?NumericQ /; Im[a] > 0` for stricter matching.